# Marshal / unmarshal domain instance to JSON in Grails

Tags: json, grails, grails-orm, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm trying to marshal and unmarshal a domain (e.g. OrgUnit) instance as JSON to a database field like this:

```
class OrgUnit{
  String name
  OrgUnit parent
  static hasMany = [children:orgUnit]
}

class History{
  String data
}

class OrgUnitService{

  History marshal(OrgUnit orgUnit){
      return new History([
          data : (orgUnit.properties as JSON).toString()
          ]).save()

  }

  OrgUnit unmarshal(History history){
     return OrgUnit.newInstance( JSON.parse(history.data))
  }
}
```

It works fine for simple fields like name, but fields like children are empty in the unmarshaled object.

The history.data field contains children information like this:

```
{"name":"b","children":[{"class":"demo.OrgUnit","id":3,"children":null,"name":"c"}]}
```

I'm using Grails 2.2.4.
Any suggestions !?

**Update**
I tested it on Grails 2.4.3. It works as expected. The content of the history.data field is in both Grails versions identical. The issue is in the unmarshaling part.

Comment: Maybe try json slurper? http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html
For me it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical part is the creation of a domain instance by *properties* map. It is used in the default *save* action in controllers. It might be a security issue in controller, but I take it out of scope there.

In Grails version 2.2.4 it doesn't bind the referencies to the instance. 
The workaround there is, to do it manually like this:

```
class HistoryService {

    def grailsApplication

    History marshal(OrgUnit orgUnit) {
        return new History([
            data: (orgUnit.properties as JSON).toString()
        ]).save(failOnError: true)

    }

    OrgUnit unmarshal(History history) {
        def data = JSON.parse(history.data)
        OrgUnit instance = OrgUnit.newInstance(data)
        def domainClass = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(OrgUnit.class.name)

        domainClass.persistentProperties.each{p->
            if (p.oneToMany || p.manyToMany){
                def refDataList = data."$p.name"
                refDataList.each{refData->
                    instance."$p.name" << getDomainClass(refData.class).read(refData.id as Long) 
                }
            }else if (p.manyToOne || p.oneToOne){
                def refData = data."$p.name"
                if(refData && refData.class && refData.id){ // if reference field has value null
                    instance."$p.name" = getDomainClass(refData.class).read(refData.id as Long)
                }
            }
        }

        return instance
    }

    private def getDomainClass(String domainName){
        return grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass(domainName)
    }
}
```